# JMeter - HashMap / LoopController Exception log

Tags: jmeter

What is the main cause of the following error log?

> 2015/09/09 10:47:42 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed!
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.(LinkedHashMap.java:412)
>     at java.util.LinkedHashMap.newEntryIterator(LinkedHashMap.java:419)
>     at java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.iterator(HashMap.java:1078)   at
>   java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1632)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.recoverRunningVersion(AbstractTestElement.java:499)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.reInitialize(GenericController.java:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsNull(GenericController.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:226)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:180)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:151)
>
> {repeats for the next ~ 900 lines}

My test plan looks as follows:

```
Testplan
- Authentication Transaction Controller
- Forever Loop
   - Random Order Controller
     - Simple Controller A
       - Only Once Controller
         - Parameterized Controller
           - Module Controller (to "Simple Controller 1")
       - For Each Loop (loops variables set by "BeanShell Post Processor 1")
         - Module Controller (to "Simple Controller 2")
     - Simple Controller B
     - Simple Controller C
Disabled Thread Group
- Simple Controller 1
   - Transaction Controller
      - HTTP Request
         - BeanShell Post Processor 1 (for JSON Extraction)
- Simple Controller 2
   - Transaction Controller
      - HTTP Request
         - BeanShell Post Processor 2 (for JSON Extraction)
```

Note: I am handling with user variables a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that the problem lives somewhere in your Beanshell PostProcessors, for instance there is some code which causes endless loop or something. If you could post response and Beanshell PostProcessor code I could be more specific. For now I can recommend the following:

1. Consider switching from Beanshell PostProcessors to [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) if extracting JSON is their only duty
2. If not - in general it isn't recommended to use Beanshell as it has some known performance problems and it's abandoned for > 10 years. Switch to [JSR223 Post Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and groovy language instead. Groovy is even more Java-compatible than Beanshell so if you didn't use anything Beanshell-specific you won't have to rewrite a single line of code. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performanceb) for Beanshell versus JSR223 benchmark, installation instructions for groovy scripting engine and scripting best practices.